# Auto increment column depending other columns value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm very new to Postgresql or SQL in general, so my terminology will probably be off.
I'm trying to add a version number column to my text text table.

| name | type | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text_id | uuid | unique id |
| post_id | uuid | id of the collection of versions |
| version_nr | INT | version number of document |
| created_at | TIMESTAMP | when the document was edited |

So basically when I create a new row I want to increment the version number, but I don't want all the rows to share the same "increment". I want all rows sharing the same post_id to have their own "increment".

This is what I've come up with this far:

```sql
CREATE TABLE text (
    text_id        uuid                      PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V4(),
    post_id        uuid                      NOT NULL,
    version_nr     SERIAL                      -- <--- I DONT KNOW
    created_at     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

I just don't understand how to solve the version_nr part.

Thanks!

Comment: What about to create a `text_counter` column on `Posts` ? Then, in a repeatable read isolation level transaction you can get `text_counter`, increase by one, and update it each time you insert a `text` row.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93296/how-can-i-implement-a-sequence-for-each-foreign-key-value

Comment: what if a row get deleted in the middle ? what happens to version_nr?

Comment: @daniherrera ah, smart. So "repeatable read isolation level transaction" (have to read about it) protects against race conditions?

Comment: @eshirvana, repeatable read will deal with deleted. If you are not sure then use `serializable isolation level`